# Disable Weblogic External Entitiy Resolution

Tags: java, xml, oracle, weblogic, code-injection

I want to harden a Weblogic Server against XXE. I know how to set the properties in the respective parsers (SAX, StAX, etc). However, I stumbled upon XML External Entity Resolution via XML Registries configuration of Weblogic itself. It is described how to cache external entities but not how to disable them by default.

How do I disable External Entity Resolution in the Weblogic itself?

Your help is very appreciated.
Thanks & Best regards